# Set ViewController when app/scene enters foreground in iOS 13

Tags: swift, ios13

My application works as many, typically banking, apps do: when the user moves the app into background (e.g. by tapping on the Home button), the current visible `ViewController` is replaced by a launch screen. When the app is brought back to foreground, it displays the previous `ViewController` or some other `ViewController` (which depends on a number of conditions, such as, for example, the duration the app was in the background, etc. - but these are not important here).

On iOS 12 and earlier, I use a very simple mechanism - on `applicationDidEnterBackground`, I set the current `ViewController` to a local variable on `AppDelegate` and display the launch screen.

```
savedViewController = window?.rootViewController
```

On `applicationWillEnterForeground`, I check whether all required conditions are met and set the `Window`'s `ViewController` to the stored `ViewController`.

```
window?.rootViewController = savedViewController
```

This no longer works on iOS 13. When the app enters foreground, the initial story boars is displayed. Setting the `rootViewController` on the current `Window` has no affect at all.

I tried to solve this issue by enabling scenes in my application, but that didn't work either.

In `SceneDelegate`, I'm able to set a default `ViewController`in the `scene:willConnecTo` method like this:

```
guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }

window = UIWindow(frame: windowScene.coordinateSpace.bounds)
window?.windowScene = windowScene

let launchStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "LaunchScreenVersion", bundle: Bundle.main)
let launchViewController = launchStoryboard.instantiateInitialViewController()

window?.rootViewController = launchViewController
window?.becomeKey()
```

The above code works, but the method is only called when the scene first loads. I then tried to move my code from from `applicationWillEnterForeground` to `sceneWillEnterForeground`, but this didn't work either. When I set the `Window`'s `ViewController` in this method, that doesn't have any effect and only the `ViewController` set initially loads.

I also tried moving the code to `sceneDidBecomeActive`, but it had exactly the same effect.

I know that iOS has built-in state restoration, but, due to security policies, we can't use them in the app as no user state can be saved if the app is no longer running.

Any ideas how I can swap the `ViewController` with a splash screen when the app goes into background and set it back when the app goes into foreground?